# Google drive file upload not working in Android Webview

Tags: java, android, html, file-upload, android-webview

I'm working on uploading file to WebView.
Local files work well. But files from google drive do not work.
URI information of local file is not empty.(not null)

Local file : content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/xxx

Google Drive File : content://com.google.android.apps.docs.storage/document/xxx

This is my code.

```
...
       takeFileResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
            int resultCode = result.getResultCode();


            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Intent intent = result.getData();
                Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FileChooserDialog.class.getSimpleName());
                if (fragment instanceof DialogFragment) {
                    ((DialogFragment) fragment).dismiss();
                }

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (null == uploadValueCallBack) {
                        return;
                    }
                    if (intent != null) {
                        Uri uri = intent.getData();
                        intent.setData(uri);
                    }

                    uploadUris = WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
                    uploadValueCallBack.onReceiveValue(uploadUris);
                    uploadValueCallBack = null;

                } else if (null != uploadMessage) {
                    Uri resultUri = (intent == null) ? null : intent.getData();
                    uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(resultUri);
                    uploadMessage = null;
                }

            }


        });
...


       Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
       i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                   
       String[] fileMimeTypes = {
                            "application/pdf",
                            "application/zip",
                            "image/*",
                    };
       
       i.setType("*/*");
       i.putExtra(EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, fileMimeTypes);
       takeFileResultLauncher.launch(Intent.createChooser(i, "File Chooser"));


...
```

I dont know the reason that happens.
Maybe do I have to check the webpage??

please help me... :(

Answer (score 0):

I saved the google drive file locally and send that local uri to webview.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(savedLocalFile(uri));
WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams.parseResult(resultCode, intent);
```

The `savedLocalFile()` function returns a `File` stored in local(or external) storage.

If you have any better ideas, please give leave comments.